# LUIS inconsistent datetimeV2 parsing (US and UK formats)

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-language-understanding

As far as I'm aware, LUIS only comes in the en-US culture for English (there's no en-UK). Therefore, I'd expect the datetimeV2 entities to come back as YYYY-DD-MM. However ***sometimes*** LUIS sends back datetimeV2 entities as YYYY-MM-DD, and it's impossible to tell when this happens programtically.

Example:

Utterance "take time off 01/03/2019 to 04/03/2019" resolves as the US YYYY-DD-MM format:

```
[ { timex: '(2019-01-03,2019-04-03,P90D)',
    type: 'daterange',
    start: '2019-01-03',
    end: '2019-04-03' } ]
```

HOWEVER, utterance "take time off 1st march 2019 to 4th march 2019" or "take time off march 1st 2019 to march 4th 2019" resolves as the UK YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
[ { timex: '(2019-03-01,2019-03-04,P3D)',
    type: 'daterange',
    start: '2019-03-01',
    end: '2019-03-04' } ]
```

In addition, if the date is written as DD/MM/YYYY when the month > 12, the format is switched to YYYY-MM-DD once again. E.g. "take time off 01/03/2019 to 18/03/2019" resolves to the first date as YYYY-DD-MM and the second date as YYYY-MM-DD:

```
[ { timex: '(2019-01-03,2019-03-18,P74D)',
    type: 'daterange',
    start: '2019-01-03',
    end: '2019-03-18' } ]
```

this makes it very hard to parse dates if the formats keep changing. How can I ensure every date range is formatted as YYYY-DD-MM? Or even YYYY-MM-DD, I don't care as long as it's ***consistent*** or at least tells me what format it has used.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to see in your question.

The 1st one is about the first two items: there is a mistake in your assessment here:

> Utterance "take time off 01/03/2019 to 04/03/2019" resolves as the US
>   YYYY-DD-MM format:
>
> ```
> [ { timex: '(2019-01-03,2019-04-03,P90D)',
>     type: 'daterange',
>     start: '2019-01-03',
>     end: '2019-04-03' } ]
> ```

The resolution here is not the US (`YYYY-DD-MM`) format, it is in UK format `YYYY-MM-DD` because as you can see, there is a duration mention of `P90D`: 90 days between both dates, so 3 months.

---

For your last item, the reason is different. It can be explained when you have a look to how it is working. For such cases, you have to understand how this items recognition is working: as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text#utilizing-the-project), LUIS uses `Microsoft.Recognizers.Text` to do this entity extraction from texts:

> Microsoft.Recognizers.Text powers pre-built entities in both LUIS:
>   Language Understanding Intelligent Service and Microsoft Bot
>   Framework; and is also available as standalone packages (for the base
>   classes and the different entity recognizers).

All this solution is open-sourced, here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text so we can analyse.

The available cultures in .Net version are listed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text/blob/master/.NET/Microsoft.Recognizers.Text/Culture.cs

```
public const string English = "en-us";
public const string EnglishOthers = "en-*";
public const string Chinese = "zh-cn";
public const string Spanish = "es-es";
public const string Portuguese = "pt-br";
public const string French = "fr-fr";
public const string German = "de-de";
public const string Italian = "it-it";
public const string Japanese = "ja-jp";
public const string Dutch = "nl-nl";
public const string Korean = "ko-kr";
```

I made a quick demo to see what is the output with your data, using the `Culture` possibilities provided by the Recognizers (as I don't know which `English` is used in LUIS):

```
Recognizing 'take time off 01/03/2019 to 18/03/2019'

**English**

01/03/2019 to 18/03/2019
{
  "values": [
    {
      "timex": "(2019-01-03,2019-03-18,P74D)",
      "type": "daterange",
      "start": "2019-01-03",
      "end": "2019-03-18"
    }
  ]
}

**English Others**

01/03/2019 to 18/03/2019
{
  "values": [
    {
      "timex": "(2019-03-01,2019-03-18,P17D)",
      "type": "daterange",
      "start": "2019-03-01",
      "end": "2019-03-18"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, my 1st result is matching yours so I guess LUIS is based on `English` culture, so `en-US` if you have a look above.

Based on this, you can see in the implementation that for the US version, it is trying to match YYYY-DD-MM first and YYYY-MM-DD is a fallback, so the 1st date of your sentence is using the 1st matching (recognized as 3rd of January) whereas the 2nd date is using the fallback (recognized as 18th of March)

Comment: thanks Nicolas - to my first point, I meant the dates are interpreted that way as opposed to resolved that way- the request is for the 1st to the 4th march, so 3 days instead of 90.

Wrt the culture, I'm using the LUIS endpoint API in Node.js, so creating a query string based on the utterance e.g. https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/[redacted]?q=take time off 1/03/19 to 4/03/19&culture=en-*. I've tried setting the culture to en-* but to no avail, it's just ignored. Do you know if it is possible to set the culture this way or do I have to change the way it's written?

Comment: No, there is no way to set the culture like that, Culture is set in LUIS app (with only language, no countryCode). For the 1st point, yes your dates in DD/MM/YYYY are interpreted as MM/DD/YYYY for the same reason as the last point of my answer: it depends on the order of the tests inside Recognizers sources... looks like it is testing `MM/DD/YYYY` before `DD/MM/YYYY`